# detail disclosure indicator on UIButton

Tags: iphone

Is there a simple way to place a detail disclosure icon on a UIButton? I'm using a navigation controller and I want a button press to push a new view on the stack, so I thought a detail disclosure icon would be appropriate, but I haven't found a straightforward way to do that yet.

What I have in mind is something like the "When Timer Ends" button in the Timer subview of the Clock app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "When Timer Ends" "button" isn't really a button, but a heavily styled UITableViewCell.

Of course you can still implement it as a button. Just create 2 images containing the disclosure indicator, and use `-setBackgroundImage:forState:`.

Comment: Where do I get the disclosure indicator image?

Comment: @Ben: Unfortunately, you need to draw it yourself.

Comment: Grab a screenshot of one from the Simulator, use Photoshop (or similar)'s Levels tool to make the image black-on-white, then use that (inverted) as a mask for whatever color of indicator you want.

Answer (score 14):

Just create a UIButton and set its `buttonType` property to `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`!

Comment: In Swift: `var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)`